# Set value of Asp DropDown List is not Working

Tags: c#, dropdownlistfor

I have an asp.net DropDownList that I use to filter a RadGrid.  After the filter has been applied I can click on a row to edit the record on a separate page.  I have a requirement to provide the ability, if the wrong row was selected, to return to the previous search page and display the same records with the same filter. I have taken care of the return and showing the same filtered records.

I also need to show the same value in the dropdown list that was chosen to create the filter.  I am trying to do this using a session variable.  The session variable gets created on the search click and I am trying to select the same item from the drop down using this code when the user returns to the search page.

```
string value = (Session["ComplaintType"] != null) ? Session["ComplaintType"].ToString() : String.Empty;
                ddlComplaint.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
```

It is not working ant I get this error message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Not sure why I am getting that error the string value is equal to the text value of the item selected from the Drop down??

Comment: make sure your session variable is not null, it will fail if you try to do the !=null and .ToString in else statement if it is null will give you that error

Comment: Thanks  I have checked and the session variable is returning the same text value that was chosen in the dropdown.

Comment: you are saying Text Value?  Verify you are comparing the VALUE (which is code behind you dont see) or the TEXT that is what you see in the UI.

Comment: I select XYZ from the dropdownlist and when I return from the edit page back to the search page the Session variable is equal to XYZ.

Comment: WHat you see in the UI may not match what the back end VALUE is.  The display value (that you see) and the VALUE can be different depending on how your code is setup

Comment: like this:  <asp:DropDownList id="ColorList"
                    AutoPostBack="True"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="Selection_Change"
                    runat="server">

                  <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="White"> White </asp:ListItem>
                  
                  <asp:ListItem Value="DarkGray"> Dark Gray </asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="DarkKhaki"> Dark Khaki </asp:ListItem>

               </asp:DropDownList>

The word Dark Grey you see, is not what the VALUE is (it is DarkGrey)

Comment: see here for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: My Dropdown list is bound to a database that has 2 column the ID number and the Text value for the item. So it is not a matching problem.

Comment: Your trying to compare your ID to the text you are seeing and they wont match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186542/discussion-between-perry-and-brad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by setting the dropdownlist selected value in the BindDropDown method where I bind the database to the database.  Once it was bound I could select a value from the database as the default value.